# Print file from specific string using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file like as shown below:

Set the prompt to the specified format. The default is mysql>. The special 
sequences that the prompt can contain are described in Section 4.5.1.2, “mysql Commands”.
The connection **protocol** to use for connecting to the server. It is useful when the 
other connection parameters normally would cause a protocol to be used other than the one you 
want. For details on the permissible values, see Section 4.2.2, “Connecting to the MySQL 
Server”.Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'

I want to print file from **protocol** string from the first occurance using shell script

Thanks

Comment: You should give your samples in readable format and tell us your intended output. Showing some attempts to solve it would also help.

Comment: It sounds like you need `sed -n '/protocol/,$p' yourfile`, but that depends on whether I'm interpreting your requirements correctly.  While I know where to find the MySQL documentation, you should provide the URL in your question — if we really need to look.  But I don't think that's very relevant, in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `grep`:

```
grep -o 'protocol.*' file.txt
```

But there are many more solutions.